# name for two quavers = one crotchet, one quaver, as a triplet

Tags: notation, sheet-music, rhythm

Excuse me if this has been asked before, but what is the notation called when after the timing there is:

> two quavers = one crotchet, one quaver, as a triplet

An example is on [this music](http://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0074969)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [swung eighths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28jazz_performance_style%29); more loosely, the music has "swing". More precisely, I'd refer to it as "triplet swung eighths" or "triplet feel" if the intent is more of a 2/3,1/3 breakdown. In blues influenced music, it might be referred to as a [[blues] shuffle](http://bestbluesguitarlessonsonline.com/bluesshuffle).  In classical music it is referred to as [notes inégales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_in%C3%A9gales).

Jazz purists may balk at the term "swung" (or swing) since in that idiom, the term swing conveys a rhythmic feel that is distinct from whether the initial eighth is elongated (that's why it's indicated as being loose talk).

Answer (score 0):

It is quaver triplets. Often called 'swing' time. Obviously easier to write out and read as standard quavers, the first being played twice as long as the third.